# Replacing a compressor/whistle with speaker for coaching program?

Tags: speakers

We have a current setup of using a whistle in coaching situations for starting sequences. I built a small RaspPi box that, through a 12 V relay, will enable a compressor with a regular coach whistle attached. I'd like to replace this with a speaker that plays a tone. I would need a speaker that can output around 120 dB in a lower frequency. Maybe around 2.5 kHz.

Ideally this is a compact speaker. I am packing everything into a portable box so weight is also a consideration. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best tool for the job, based on the stated requirements, is a sound siren. You can get a 12V model with a built-in generator for a couple USD/EUR, and it will get you 120dB.